# adding a highlight effect, css float

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a highlight effect, where text that is hovered over is labeled in black. The structure of the html will have this content floating to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hj5D/

The problem is that I only want to highlight the WORD, not the entire area of the `div` tag. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to wrap the textual content in an additional element and add the background color attribute to it.  For example a `<span>` element.

```
<div id="item 4" class="command"><span>item 4</span></div>
```

Then your jQuery code would look something like this -

```
$('.command').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass("select");
    },function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("select");
});
```

Or you could just add the hover event to the internal `<span>` -

```
$('.command > span').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("select");
    },function() {
    $(this).removeClass("select");
});
```

#### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6hj5D/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, by 'word,' you mean to colour the background of the *text* (rather than each individual word), the following should achieve that aim, by wrapping the contents of the hovered-over `.command` element in a `span` with the `select` class-name:

```
$('.command').hover(function() {
    $(this).html(
        function(i,h){
            return '<span class="select">' + h + '</span>';
        });
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('.command').find('span').contents().unwrap();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6hj5D/10/).

It is, as Lix correctly notes in the comments, important to remember that with this solution all of the contents of the hovered-over element will be wrapped in a `span` (given that this may include block-level elements, perhaps a `div` would be a better choice) and, on `mouseleave`  this will remove all contained spans from the element. These comments being accurate, I'd amend the above to the following, in order to be more valid on `mouseenter` specific, and more specific on `mouseleave`:

```
$('.command').hover(function() {
    $(this).html(
        function(i,h){
            return '<div class="select">' + h + '</div>';
        });
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('.command').find('div.select').contents().unwrap();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6hj5D/12/).

With this latter suggestion I've amended the CSS in order to highlight only the text (as a `div` behaves differently to a `span`), to the following:

```
.select {
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the HTML content given was some dummy content.  With this solution one must be aware that the entire content of the `<div>` element will be wrapped with a `<span>` on hover.  And when hovering out, **ALL** content of **ALL** spans will be unwrapped from its containing `<span>`.

Comment: @Lix: agreed; I've edited to make those points more obvious, and proposed a slight amendment to the originally-posted code that should, hopefully, be a little less troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .select class to:

```
.select{ color:red; white-space:pre}
```

Background colour has been removed (from your original .select). The color property could be any color you wanted as the highlight color.

You can find out more about css here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference

Comment: What do you mean by `"Background colour has been removed."`?

Comment: The OP said they wanted to highlight the word, not the entire div. Looking at their fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6hj5D/ the background of the div was black, which was causing the whole div to be hightlighted.  So by removing  .select {background: #000.. } only the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS, just modify/add this to your `CSS`:

```
.command{
   margin-left:50%;
   display:inline;
}
.command:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}
```